# Radius of convergence of a complex function with a Taylor Series expansion

Tags: complex-analysis

> The function
>   $$f(z)=\frac{1}{1+i-\sqrt{2}z}$$
>   has a Taylor series expansion around $z_0=0$. What is its radius of convergence?

So far I have computed the singularity point to be $z = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}i$ So therefore We take the distance from $z_0$ to this singular point is $1$. Please can someone confirm this for me.

Comment: That's correct. The radius of convergence is the distance from the center to the nearest singularity, which is $1$ in this case.

Comment: @MPW:  saw your user page, we have similar interests, mine tending to Greek, Hebrew, music, math, cannabis (rather than beer!) Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

One also get at the radius of convergence like this:

Set

$\alpha = \dfrac{1 + i}{\sqrt{2}}; \tag{1}$

then

$\vert \alpha \vert = 1 \tag{2}$

and so

$\vert \alpha^{-1} \vert = 1 \tag{3}$

as well; we write

$f(z) = \dfrac{1}{1 + i - \sqrt{2}z} = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \dfrac{1}{\alpha - z} = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2} \alpha} \dfrac{1}{1 - \alpha^{-1} z}; \tag{4}$

for $\vert z \vert < 1$ we have

$\vert \alpha^{-1} z \vert = \vert \alpha^{-1} \vert \vert z \vert < 1; \tag{5}$

thus the series

$\dfrac{1}{1 - \alpha^{-1} z} = 1 + \alpha^{-1}z + \alpha^{-2}z^2 + \ldots = \sum_0^\infty (\alpha^{-1} z)^n \tag{6}$

converges.  Allowing $\vert z \vert = 1$, we may take $z = \alpha$ and not only is

$\dfrac{1}{(1 - \alpha^{-1} z)} = \dfrac{1}{(1 - \alpha^{-1} \alpha)} = \dfrac{1}{1 - 1} \tag{7}$

undefined, but

$\sum_0^\infty (\alpha^{-1} z)^n = \sum_0^\infty (\alpha^{-1} \alpha)^n = \sum_0^\infty 1^n = \infty; \tag{8}$

the series clearly explodes for $z = \alpha$.  Since this series converges for $\vert z \vert < 1$ but not for $z = \alpha$, the radius of convergence is clearly $1$.  The same holds for the series of $f(z)$, by (4).

Comment: A series which "explodes" ?